# A memory warning when replacing a root viewController with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c

I could see that when i am replacing the root viewController without animation, everything works great, but when i am adding animation to it , its of course looks better, but it gives me a memory warning at the moment of the transition .

I am using iPad Air , I guess its because at that moment there are 2 views in the stack ??
Should i ignore it, or there is anything i can do ?

```
 UIViewController *mainV=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainView"];
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [UIView transitionFromView:delegate.window.rootViewController.view
                        toView:mainV.view
                      duration:0.75f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         delegate.window.rootViewController=mainV;


     }];
```

Answer (score 0):

Placed your code in the dispatch_asynch and check:-

```
UIViewController *mainV=[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"mainView"];
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    [UIView transitionFromView:delegate.window.rootViewController.view
                        toView:mainV.view
                      duration:0.75f
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                    completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
         delegate.window.rootViewController=mainV;
});


     }];
});
```

Comment: thanks but it didn't work, it made it even worse. the moment i switch views i get a memory warning.

Comment: putting a UI animation not in the main thread is a bad practice,you don't do that, and i don't see why its going to change a thing. (it actually make it worse).